# I can Be A Thing, A Person or Two Thoughts

Tags: word

I Can Be A Thing, A Person or Two Thoughts
Two ideas connect in your head,
Like a string of chains,
I can go to the past, and between worlds.

I attach from your head to your hands,
and tell you whether you’re touching something hot or cold,
Signature green, and metallic grey,
I live up high, that’s where I rule.

Hint 1:

> Better Brush Up on your video game knowledge!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! I didn't downvote, but I suspect it was because you posted a riddle. Riddles are *very* common here, and without rhyme scheme or some other interesting 'trick' such as wordplay, they simply aren't very creative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so the clue makes it easier.... I think...

> Is it "Link"?
>
>  Link is a video game character, the protagonist of the *Legend of Zelda* series. The word "link" can also mean a connection, or two objects being connected.
>
>  Chains are made of links.
>
>  One of the video games featuring him is A Link *To The Past*, which debuted on the SNES.  Another is A Link *Between Worlds* for the 3DS.
>
> The "hot and cold" thing is probably about your nerves linking your extremities to your brain.
>
> Signature green and metallic grey has to do with his iconic green tunic as well as the sword he wields in his adventures, often the Master Sword.
>
> The last bit almost works in two ways.  Link is typically found within the land of Hyrule.  The last line has the words "high" and "rule."  Also "I rule" alone sounds like Hyrule.

Can someone please help edit this so my answer is hidden? I don't know what is wrong

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, and great answer - I think that's it! Yeah, spoiler markup is weird - you have to add two spaces at the end of every line. I'll edit your post to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a

> BRAIN

I Can Be A Thing, A Person or Two Thoughts

> the word brain can be used in different ways, as described above

Two ideas connect in your head,
Like a string of chains,

> Synapsis

I can go to the past, and between worlds.

> Memories and Fantasy

I attach from your head to your hands,
and tell you whether you’re touching something hot or cold,
Signature green, and metallic grey,

> The brain creates all emotions and feelings thus connects not only to hands but all parts of the body

I live up high, that’s where I rule.

> Up high = in the head (which is right on top usually)